# MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion freezes frequently (full screen Flash in Chrome, Messages, HTC on USB)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, usb, performance

Problems following an upgrade to Mountain Lion on a 13-inch, Early 2011 MacBook Pro (MacBookPro8,1 with Intel HD Graphics 3000).

With Google Chrome, I was watching YouTube video fullscreen – Flash content. In the middle of video, I wanted to exit full-screen mode but neither the keyboard nor the trackpad worked. The video continued playing fine. At last, I forced the system to close and restarted.

Today I was just chatting in Messages and suddenly everything froze. I was able to move the cursor but nothing was happening.

Has anyone else faced this issue, or found a solution?

Update:
If I connect my mobile phone (HTC Wildfire S) to my MacBook Pro using USB, the Mac freezes every time while removing the USB connector.

Comment: Duplicate of my question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58197/mountain-lion-hang-but-mouse-still-worked

Comment: I get this upon a reboot when I open an app sometimes. At first I thought it was Microsoft Lync causing the issue, but I've since had it with Firefox and Evernote. Upon a forced reboot all is well, but I don't like doing this.

Comment: A very similar question but @Caesium is happy to work remotely with `ssh`. As we can't assume the same here, answers may offer a subtly different approach.

Comment: @Vivart, please: what model is your MacBook Pro? Which browser did you use? Do you prefer Flash or HTML5 for video in YouTube? A combination of factors may contribute to this case.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin i have 13-inch, Early 2011 macbook pro. I was using chrome browser for flash video on youtube.

Comment: Thanks. Did you use the Adobe Flash Player method for full screen, without full screen Safari? Or did you have full screen Safari before adding full screen Flash to the mix? Can you offer the URL of the YouTube page that was in use when the issue occurred?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Suspect an issue affecting the WindowServer process (long edition)

- a [more generic edition of this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87982/8546) appears under [How do you get system diagnostic files from OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/59917/8546)
- power users may prefer to read nearby [Suspect an issue affecting the WindowServer process (brief edition …)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58590/8546)

---

The symptoms you describe are familiar but not commonplace and in my case, not frequent.

### Prepare for diagnosis

In Terminal, run the following command. Be prepared to enter your admin password for the operating system:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.stackshot.plist
```

Take a written note of the following key chord, you'll need it later:

<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>

### Diagnosis by the system

When the problem occurs:

1. use the key chord
2. for at least ten seconds, touch nothing
3. allow maybe five or ten minutes for all parts of the so-called `sysdiagnose` routine to complete – simply wait as long as you can (with this approach there'll be no on-screen indication of progress)
4. force a restart of the computer (Command-Control-Power).

After the computer starts:

1. in Finder, go to `/private/var/tmp`
2. seek a file or folder with a name beginning *sysdiagnose_*
3. if that file or folder exists, move it to a convenient place – your desktop, maybe.

#### Hint

Whilst I don't encourage carelessness, you can be a little careless with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> … if you struggle to avoid the <kbd>fn</kbd> key on your laptop, don't worry; including it by accident should not prevent the run of `sysdiagnose`.

---

### Human analysis of diagnosis by the system

Hint: someone might like to ask a separate question about analysing the results of `sysdiagnose` – a more generalised answer could be useful.

#### If sysdiagnose_… from the `/tmp` area is a folder

Presence of a `sysdiagnose_…` folder (not a `.tar.gz` file) indicates that either:

- the routine was interrupted before completion; or
- some part of the routine could not complete.

#### If sysdiagnose_… from the `/tmp` area is a file

Presence of a `sysdiagnose_….tar.gz` file indicates that all parts of the `sysdiagnose` routine completed, and that the results were archived. If you wish, open the archive – its contents will appear as a folder.

#### Folder contents at a glance

In the first screenshot below – an example of a **completed** run of `sysdiagnose` - I have selected two of the items that may be of interest in a case such as this.

[image: Screenshot of a decompressed sysdiagnose_….tar.gz archive]

Note that it may be normal to find at least one empty file.

[image: crashes_and_spins gathered by sysdiagnose – screenshot of an example]

Amongst the `.crash`, `.hang` and `.spin` files – or in the `top.txt` file – might be a good sign of what was wrong shortly before, or during, the period when you lost control of the computer.

Related:

- [How does 'stuck' (in results of 'top') relate to 'not responding' (in Activity Monitor), 'spin' or 'hang'?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58697/8546)

For an **incomplete** run of `sysdiagnose` it may be useful to focus some attention on files that are **abnormally** empty …

---

### Technical

[stackshot(1) OS X Manual Page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150923125121/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/stackshot.1.html)

[sysdiagnose(1) OS X Manual Page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150923121728/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/sysdiagnose.1.html)

Comment: I have tried this and i got a folder in /tmp with bunch of files.

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance. If eventually you discover the cause(s) of the problem in your case, I'll be glad to know - please leave a comment either here, or under your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the Android File Transfer App.
Uninstall it and the problem will go away.

Still I think google should address this..