# How does 'stuck' (in results of 'top') relate to 'not responding' (in Activity Monitor), 'spin' or 'hang'?

Tags: command-line, performance, activity-monitor

In results of `top` commands, I sometimes see *stuck*.

Apple's [top(1) OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html) does not explain this use of the word.

How, if it all, does *stuck* relate to the following?

1. *not responding* – may be seen in Activity Monitor, in the Force Quit Applications dialogue of loginwindow, and so on
2. `.hang` files – may be present at `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`
3. `.spin` files – may be present at `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`

---

There's an an accepted answer for the first point. Answers relating to points 2 and 3 will be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is usually no correlation between a *stuck* process of `top` and a non-responding application:

- *stuck* means that the process is currently un-interruptible which usually is the case if the process is waiting for a disk or network data block to be read (or similar low-level stuff). Technically speaking the process is executing in kernel space (aka Unix kernel) and can not be interrupted (so even a `kill -9` wouldn't have any impact). Usually these *stuck* states only last milliseconds (as you can see in `top` as well because the number of *stuck* processes changes with every display cycle).
- *non-responding applications* can be *too* busy to reply to any event OS X throws at them.

I see one situation where a *stuck* process corresponds to a non-responding application: A process can be *stuck* for a very long time, perhaps stuck endlessly, without any possibility to kill it. This usually is the result of some programming error, e.g. improper disconnection from a networked device then the kernel keeps trying to read from it. In cases like this even a forced termination will not remove the process.

Comment: Thanks – if *stuck* is synonymous with *uninterruptible*, then I'm familiar with that state. `uninterruptible` is commonly seen when I key Control-T ([SIGINFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINFO)) whilst running `fsck_hfs` from the command line. More on `SIGINFO` in Apple's [termios(4) OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/termios.4.html).

Comment: Related to this answer, a question in Stack Overflow may be of interest: [How to identify not responding process programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2366190/38108).

Comment: I had a look at the source code of top: uninterruptible is the same as stuck.

Comment: Gotcha – [highlights](http://diigo.com/0s4ik) from [libtop.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/top/top-73/libtop.c) in open source for Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Answer (score 2):

## Process state U, TH_STATE_UNINTERRUPTIBLE and Linux process state D

Someone else drew attention to [MacOS top: “stuck” means “uninterruptible” | nelsonslog](http://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/macos-top-stuck-means-uninterruptible/)

> … `TH_STATE_UNINTERRUPTIBLE`, which I believe is
>   what `ps` reports as process state “U”. I’m guessing this is what Linux
>   calls “D” for “Device Wait”. In which case, in most cases the process
>   is fine, it’s waiting for some I/O to complete. …

The [Ubuntu man page for ps](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/ps.1.html) confirms a process state code –

> `D    Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)`

– with no other mention of *uninterruptible*.

In FreeBSD/Linux Linux Kernel Cross-Reference:

- [TH_STATE_UNINTERRUPTIBLE](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/trackident?i=TH_STATE_UNINTERRUPTIBLE)

I found a 2002 discussion [The Answer Gang 83: How to kill a process in uninterruptible sleep state?](http://linuxgazette.net/issue83/tag/6.html) ([highlights](http://diigo.com/0s4j6)) that fits nicely with the observations made by @patrix.

Last but not least, a 2004 post [[X-Unix] PS and Stuck Processes](http://listserver.themacintoshguy.com/pipermail/x-unix/2004-March/000413.html) ([highlights](http://diigo.com/0s4j8)) mentioning **WindowServer**, which fits nicely with the [hang](/questions/tagged/hang)-related question that prompted me to post the question here:

- [MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion freezes frequently (full screen Flash in Chrome, Messages, HTC on USB)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58297/8546)