# What is a "stuck" process?

Tags: macos, unix

Using the **top** command in Terminal, and ordering the list by state, I see a number of processes on Yosemite 10.10.1 whose state is **stuck**. I've looked through **man ps** and **man top** for an explanation, and done some googling, without enlightenment.

Nothing's apparently wrong with the system - in fact, coreaudiod (one of the stuck processes) is racking up CPU and merrily driving the sound system - but I'm curious what is "stuck" about them and whether this is cause for concern.

```
Processes: 198 total, 2 running, 5 stuck, 191 sleeping, 747 threads                                                                          21:42:18
Load Avg: 1.23, 1.21, 1.17  CPU usage: 0.72% user, 1.44% sys, 97.83% idle  SharedLibs: 15M resident, 15M data, 0B linkedit.
MemRegions: 367655 total, 2827M resident, 92M private, 294M shared. PhysMem: 7320M used (912M wired), 870M unused.
VM: 481G vsize, 1064M framework vsize, 0(0) swapins, 0(0) swapouts. Networks: packets: 41886204/42G in, 35471289/14G out.
Disks: 491864/8916M read, 1290630/36G written.

PID    COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH  #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPR PGRP  PPID  STATE    BOOSTS           %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS UID  FAULTS    COW
261    coreaudiod   1.0  01:12.19 5    1    206   2412K  0B     0B   261   1     stuck    *0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    202  233919    198
231    accountsd    0.0  00:01.74 3    1    70    5092K  0B     0B   231   1     stuck     0[244]          0.00000 0.00000    501  11585     418
206    distnoted    0.0  00:24.10 3    1    143   4284K  0B     0B   206   1     stuck    *0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    501  70899     90
197    coresymbolic 0.0  00:00.35 3    2    23    996K   0B     0B   197   1     stuck     0[188]          0.00000 0.00000    0    57709     124
37     mds          0.0  02:54.01 4    1    802   44M    0B     0B   37    1     stuck    *0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    0    956495    1227
92425  tccd         0.0  00:00.00 2    1    26    972K   0B     0B   92425 1     sleeping  0[3]            0.00000 0.00000    235  935       124
92414  AssetCacheLo 0.0  00:00.68 4    0    74    3232K  0B     0B   92414 1     sleeping  0[22]           0.00000 0.00000    235  5147      175
```

Comment: how did you get that info ?

Comment: Hi @Buscar웃 - that is the output of the `top` command.

Comment: There are a couple of [related questions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58697/how-does-stuck-in-results-of-top-relate-to-not-responding-in-activity-m) with informative [answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56451).

Comment: An elaborate answer to this question has been provided here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56451/121387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The significance of stuck is that the process is not running while in a state that is uninterruptible while it waits for I/O. There’s nothing wrong, just that the kernel has accepted an I/O and it’s “stuck” waiting for that response before it can be paused or sent a signal to exit (or more likely continue to run normally).

- [How does 'stuck' (in results of 'top') relate to 'not responding' (in Activity Monitor), 'spin' or 'hang'?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58697)