# Mountain Lion sometimes hangs when mouse enters Dock – pointer is movable, but the MacBook Air seems otherwise frozen

Tags: macos, dock, performance

I have a mid-2011 13" MacBook Air (MacBookAir4,2 with Intel HD Graphics 3000).

Since installing Mountain Lion I sometimes encounter a problem when I move the mouse cursor over the dock to click something.

Sometimes I get pinwheeled, sometimes I don't.

Whenever the problem occurs:

- there appears a 75% transparent label for a dock item
- I can continue to move the mouse
- the computer does not recover, I resort to a forced shutdown.

There doesn't seem to be any common denominators yet, other than it always happens as I mouse over the dock.

Is there a log or anything I can look at to rectify the problem?

Comment: Please: what make and model is the mouse? Or do you use the integral trackpad to move the pointer? Can you provide a screenshot? Whilst the computer *appears* to not respond to the keyboard and other human input devices (HIDs), Command-Shift-3 might silently work – seek the screenshot after you next log in.

Comment: I can confirm that this appears to be fixed in the newer Intel HD3000 drivers in OS X 10.8.2, which should hopefully be released to everyone soon.

Comment: Just chiming in to say this has occurred in the last couple of weeks now, may have been rectified by a software update.

Comment: Has or has *not* occurred? ;-)

Comment: *Not*, I accidentally a word

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution to the problem, but I found that closing the lid and waiting until the computer sleeps (status led pulsing) and opening it works.
At least its better than a forced shutdown right?

Answer (score 1):

Reading this question alongside an [earlier comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58197/with-firefox-aurora-mountain-lion-hung-but-the-mouse-still-worked?lq=1#comment67561_58200) from the opening poster …

## Suspect an issue affecting WindowServer

Diagnosis by and of the system:

- [long edition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58595/8546) (an accepted answer)
- [brief edition for power users](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58590/8546)

– in a case such as this, what's gathered by `sysdiagnose` is likely to include everything that's required for human analysis of the problem.

For a focused analysis, we need more detail in the question. I'll suggest an edition and maybe add a comment …

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to the system trying to zoom in on the nearest Dock icon to your mouse (is magnification on ?) or maybe the system crashes because it can't find the font used to display Dock items name.

Have you tried to create a new user account and reproduce the issue there ? So you'll know if it's a systemwide issue or only related to your user account.

Comment: The label doe show up so I wouldn't guess it was the font, also don't have magnification on

Comment: you may see error details in /var/log/system.log file. Open the Console.app from /Applications/Utilities and display this log file. New lines will show in real time if something bad happens, like a hang or a crash. Do you see anything related to Dock there ?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your PRAM by holding <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> when turning the computer on and continuing to hold until it resets.