# Disable Stand By Mode on Retina MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, macbook-pro, power-management

I learned that the retina MacBook Pro has a Deep Sleep Mode that is initiated when left idle for a long time. This, however, causes my laptop to take about 3-5 seconds to wake up after it sleeps, such as opening the lid.

Can I disable this Deep Sleep Mode?

I would also like to know the advantages/disadvantages of disabling it. Does it really save *that* much power? I would rather have a faster wake up time than saving 1% of battery or something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To disable deep sleep, run the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo pmset -a standby 0
```

This is a description of "standby" (deep sleep) from the pmset man page:

```
 standby causes kernel power management to automatically hibernate a
 machine after it has slept for a specified time period. This saves power
 while asleep. This setting defaults to ON for supported hardware. The
 setting standby will be visible in pmset -g if the feature is supported
 on this machine.

 standby only works if hibernation is turned on to hibernatemode 3 or 25.

 standbydelay specifies the delay, in seconds, before writing the hiberna-
 tion image to disk and powering off memory for Standby.
```

Battery savings depend on how much time your Mac spends in standby. While in standby mode, your Mac consumes 0 power, it's as if it is shut down (note: not taking Power Nap into consideration).

My personal recommendation would be to set the "standbydelay" value to something bigger. 2 hours, for example. This means that if you open the lid back in less than 2 hours, your Mac would be in regular sleep and wake up instantly. If longer than 2 hours, your Mac would enter standby mode and consume no power, and waking up will take a bit longer.

Example for 2 hours:

```
sudo pmset -a standbydelay 7200
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it save a great deal of power ? Do you know how much percent would I lose by deactivating it ? Basically what are the disadvantages of turning it off ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a bit more detail about this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you also add the code to change the default value back ?? Is it 1 hour ? Also, does `sudo pmset -a standby 1` re-enable standby mode ?

Comment: Yes, sudo pmset -a standby 1 re-enables standby mode. I have no idea what the default value for standbydelay is.

Comment: It was `4200` on my MacBook Air. Apple's KB article says that `The standby mode activates after just over an hour of "regular" sleep.`.

Comment: It is 4200 on my MBPro Retina too...

Comment: I always set it to 43200 (12 hours) or 86400 (24 hours). Chances are you're plugging in your laptop every 24 hours anyway and it only saves a teeny-tiny bit of battery. Standby is great if you don't touch your computer for a week, say. Without standby, the battery would slowly drain. With standby, there's hardly any drain.