# How long before Standby/Deep sleep mode is activated?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, macbook-pro, hibernate

I recently learned that I can modify the time at which Standby mode is activated automatically when the laptop is sleeping. However, I would like to know the default value before changing anything. How long does the laptop stay in hibernation before it goes into deep sleep / standby mode ?

Platform : rMBP Mountain Lion OSX 10.8

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "standby", "hibernation" and "deep sleep"?

Comment: Check this out http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60634/disable-stand-by-mode-on-retina-macbook-pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list some power management settings with `pmset -g` (get). The default `standbydelay` was 4200 seconds (70 minutes) on my MacBook Air.

```
$ pmset -g
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            1
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                15
 hibernatemode        0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         15
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

According to [Apple Portables: About standby mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392), "the standby mode activates after just over an hour of "regular" sleep".